# How to pass arguments to Qt's DirectFB back-end?

Tags: qt, directfb

When launching an embedded Qt application by specifying the directfb back-end, there is a way to pass arguments to it by using a specific syntax

```
./my-qt-app -qws -display directfb:960x720
```

This will change the resolution.

Let's say I'd like to remove the chrome from the application window. Since directfb has lots of options, how could I specify them via command-line? Should a look for the internal Qt implementation or use CLI arguments as specified by the DirectFB project?

**UPDATE** although there is a mechanism using colons to pass arguments to the
display back-end, in the directfb case it won't work for resolution changes.

Comment: Delving into the source code, it seems that DirectFB parameters are processed
by the Linux Screen Framebuffer plugin, implemented by
`qt-4.8.5/src/gui/embedded/qscreenlinuxfb_qws.cpp`.

It does receives parameters in a colon-separated list, such as
`nographicsmodeswitch`, `genericcolors`, `tty=(.\*)` and `/dev/fb0` framebuffer device
specification, however, display resolution is calculated via an environment
variable named `QWS_SIZE` using the `"%dx%d"` format.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to pass multiple arguments is to use the standard `directfbrc` mechanism, usually located under `/etc` or the directory determined by `${DFB_CONFIG_DIR}` environment variable.

Also noticed later that things like the application window chrome are set inside Qt itself, not DirectFB.

Answer (score 0):

As @milton answered one place is /etc/directfbrc and the other way is for example:

```
./app --dfb:window-surface-policy=auto
```

you can pass help to get all the commands:

```
./app --dfb:help
```